# Textbooks in Algebraic Topology

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, algebraic-topology

I have been self-studying algebraic topology for a few months now from Hatcher's textbook and I am getting in tune with the subject, grasping ideas more firmly and being able to solve some of the exercises, however while I started to appreciate Hatcher as a mathematician after a few reads his tendency to go on and on without splitting paragraphs kind of tires me out. My question is, is Massey's book on algebraic topology a good alternative to Hatcher's chapters 0 and 1 and more user friendly or has it become a bit outdated as time went by?

Comment: Not an expert in this field, but as I have noticed it is quite hard to find a really good textbook for algebraic topoplogy, mainly because there are so many different approaches. Maybe it is best to go after some lecture notes. Besides that I enjoyed Rotman Introduction to Algebraic Topology, but this is a rather "baby text" and introduction has to be taken seriously because of that. So I do not know if you want to go through 400 pages of "Introduction".

Comment: In your academic carrer have lecture notes served you better than the textbook itself? I have been very curious about opinions on this question

Comment: Yes, I do think so. As I said, I tried several books and a lecturer/researcher in this topic knows best what you should know and bring you up to speed in this topic. There are so many different approaches. You need the language of categories, homological algebra and so on, and every book is different and treats those topics differently. But reading books is always nice. But if you can attempt a course, I would advice that.

Comment: An alternative could be May's book "A Concise Course in Algebraic Topology" which is also freely available on the internet. If your problem with Hatcher's book is the long paragraphs and intuitive approach, then i think May's book might be worth a try. It is written concisely (as the name suggests) and gets to the point faster. It is also more formal in its argumentation. However, it should be noted that it is not the easiest book.